# How to pass value from C# code to Nlog email's body

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

I'd like to pass the value from my control into nlog's email body.

nlog.config

```
<target xsi:type="Mail"
            addNewLines = "true"
            name="NewRequestemail"
            to="${adminEmail}"
            subject="Please review a new [${systemName}] "
            html="true"
            body="${exception:format=tostring}"
            from="${systemEmail}"
            smtpServer="${smtpServer}" />


    <logger name="NewRequestemail" minlevel="Info" writeTo="NewRequestemail" />
```

HomeControl.cs

```
LogManager.GetLogger("NewRequestemail").Info("body", "Test Message");
```

I am not sure what should be right away to pass the "Test Massage" into email's body.  So far, I got blank email for now.   Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `${message}`, e.g

```
body="${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
```

And logger call

```
LogManager.GetLogger("NewRequestemail").Info("my message");
```